# Change MAC adress virtual switch Windows server with Hyper-V

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, hyper-v, mac-address

I have a windows server installation in which I run Hyper-V. Hyper-V has created a Virtual switch network adapter which my Virtual Machines can use.
[Virtual switch Hyper-V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJr0Q.png)

Both of these adapters have a static IP address: the actual adapter: x.x.x.215, and the Hyper-V adapter x.x.x.214

When I look in my ipconfig /all, I can see that both this virtual switch and the actual ethernet switch of my windows server have the exact same MAC-address. While I have not had any problems with this before, I think I might now have some issues with port forwarding.

I was setting up some port forwarding in my router (Fritz!box 7590), and I noticed that the static IP address of my windows server is constantly changing between x.x.x.214 and x.x.x.215. Since in this software I have to select a device for port forwarding, and not an IP-address, it seems like I am unable to reliable port forward to x.x.x.215, since it would forward to x.x.x.214 when the IP address in my router changes. This all seems to be because both of those network adapters have the same MAC-address, and the router seems to use the MAC-address as a unique identifier. (https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/3456_FRITZ-Box-reports-A-device-with-this-name-has-already-been-configured/)

It seems to me like my only solution here (without new hardware/huge hosting changes) would be to change the MAC address of the Hyper-V adapter so I have 2 separate entries in my router, which would make sense to me. However, I can't seem to find any way to accomplish this.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me : The Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter has the MAC address of `00-15-5D-76-34-D9`, which is not the same as my Ethernet adapter. Maybe you should re-create the Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter, or reinstall the Hyper-V feature.

Comment: Interesting. I have a 'nat' virtual adapter which also had a MAC adress in that range, but that seems like it's not the 'main' Hyper-V adapter. I did end up removing it and recreating it, after which it changed my adapter settings a bit. The MAC adress of both the Hyper-V adapter and the Ethernet adapter is still the same, however.
Recreating it did make my main Ethernet adapter not have the ipv4 section enabled anymore, meaning that the only adapter with an IP address is now  the Hyper-V adapter. This actually seems like it works, and no longer confuses my router now.